# Angular 5 add baseURI to image src and can't dynamically load image

Tags: angular, typescript, image, angular5

I work on angular 5.2.1 and I want to load an image whose src comes from a server

HTML

```
<img #image [src]="cover" class="img-fluid" alt="NO image">
```

image-loader.component.ts

```
     import { Component, OnInit, Input, AfterViewInit,ViewChild,ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
    import { EventAccessService } from '../../../event/services/event-acces.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'loader',
      templateUrl: './loader.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./loader.component.scss']
    })
    export class EventCardComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
      @Input('cover') cover: any;

    @ViewChild("image", {read: ElementRef}) image: ElementRef;

      constructor(private service: EventAccessService) {

      }
    ngOnInit() {}
     ngAfterViewInit() {

        console.log(this.image.nativeElement.currentSrc);
        this.image.nativeElement.src=this.cover
        console.log(this.image.nativeElement.src);
    }
}
```

Result from chrome console :
http://localhost:4200/(which is the baseURI) concatenated to the variable `cover`(which is the full link to the image)

As a result the image doesn't load

Help Please!!

**EDIT**

I changed the `image.nativeElement.src` to `cover` directly at the `ngAfterViewInit` but still no change

Comment: Setting the `src` attribute on the child element is not what you want to do. Just set `cover` once you know the URL.

Comment: I got the answer myself....my REST api was giving me the url in the form `www.xxxx`  and angular was completing them (I don't really know why) so I added `http://`  infront of the url and all went ok...thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

Here I have used RxjS like so: i.e. you can put the image URL where it is coming from the server into  `BehaviorSubject` like below.

*.html*

```
<img [src]="photoHandlerService?.userProfilePhotoChanged$ | async" #userProfilePhoto>
```

*.ts*

```
 @ViewChild('userProfilePhoto') userProfilePhoto: ElementRef;

 constructor(public photoHandlerService: PhotoHandlerService) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.userProfilePhoto.nativeElement.src);
  }
```

*service.ts*

```
 private profilePhoto: string = 'assets/images/jpgs/profilePhoto.jpg';
 private userProfilePhotoSubject$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.profilePhoto);
 userProfilePhotoChanged$: Observable<string> = this.userProfilePhotoSubject$.asObservable();

 constructor()

setUserProfilePhoto(photoUrl: string): void {
    this.userProfilePhotoSubject$.next(photoUrl);
}
```